# Combining Two Strings into One Variable in C++

Tags: c++

I am en process of writing a simple program that assigns given student names into groups of whatever interval requested. Currently, I am focusing on the function that reads the name of the students.
Here is the code:

```
class student
{
public:
    string nameFirst;
    string nameLast;
};

student typeName()
{
    student foo;
    cout << "Type in a student's first name: ";
    cin >> foo.nameFirst;
    cout << "Type in that student's last name: ";
    cin >> foo.nameLast;
    cout << "\n";
    return foo;
}
```

Since I cannot use `getline()`, I am forced to create two strings, one for each section of the student's full name. How can I rewrite this code to allow for it to take the full name without creating two variables and without using `getline()`? Or, if such isn't possible, how can I use a method within the class to combine the two strings into one?

Comment: How about `foo.name = foo.nameFirst + " " + foo.nameLast`

Comment: Using `>>` as you have, parsing stops when whitespace is encountered, so any names with spaces will be truncated.  If you don't care, then you can recombine the words into a single name with `nameFirst + ' ' + nameLast`.  Otherwise, you may want to use e.g. `get()` to read into a character array until a newline is encountered (a poor imitation of `getline()`, so you can handle surnames like "Von Muellerhoff".  More generally, to learn what `std::string`s can do, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: There's also iterators: `foo.name.assign(istreambuf_iterator<char>(cin.rdbuf()), istreambuf_iterator<char>());` (as apposed to the preferred `std::getline()` of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use

```
cin >> foo.nameFirst >> foo.nameLast;
```

`cin >>` will parse stops at white spaces, so you can just input the full name in one line split by space like `James Bond`.

To combine two strings into one:

```
string fullName = foo.nameFirst + " " + foo.nameLast;
```